# opc test applicance, software or hardware

Tags: testing, opc-ua

I am developing a sensor that communicates via OPC UA. I am using [an open source library](https://github.com/FreeOpcUa) to implement the OPC interface. Now I would like to test against a "real world" device that would be used by a process control system.

I have implemented my sensor as an OPC server and to test it I've also written a client using the above mentioned library. I've also downloaded a [smartphone app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.prosysopc.ua.android2&hl=de) that serves as an opc client. So far my sensor works well with these clients.

However I would want to test against something inexpensive that is used in industry. I could also see myself wanting to build several simple test boxes and create my own small network.

If there is a purchasable product I'd also be interested.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [UA Expert](https://www.unified-automation.com/products/development-tools/uaexpert.html), it is free and GUI is really easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

Inductive Automation's Ignition product has both an OPC UA client and server component. You can download a full version that has a resettable 2 hour trial [here](https://inductiveautomation.com/downloads/).

You may find it worthwhile to make sure that you can set up an OPC UA connection from the Ignition gateway to your server implementation. Ignition's OPC UA client implementation is based on [Eclipse Milo](http://github.com/eclipse/milo).